# Handlebars: sending multiple documents

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Say I have the following code which returns a whole table of different fruit:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#each search_result.fruit}}
<tr>
  <td name="fruit" value={{fruit}}>{{fruit}}</td>
  <td name="color" value={{color}}>{{color}}</td>   
</tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I send back the following:

```
req.body={{"fruit": "apple", "color": "red"}, {"fruit": "banana", "color": "yellow"}}
```

Here's the bootstrap button I am using:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">UpdateFruits</button>
</div>
```

This is what it is currently sending (which I don't want):

```
req.body={"fruit":{"apple","banana"},"color":{"red","yellow"}}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!